# Observable subscription not kicking off sequence of events

Tags: java, observable

I have the following method *start* that returns an Observable.
If I subscribe to it, the operations inside the handle (they are DB insert operations)
does not seem to happen. But If I directly subscribe to the *handle* method, it works and able to perform DB insertions.

Stepping through debug, the data is all correctly captured. It just seems like the subscription didn't work as intended.
Can I please get some advice on why it doesn't work if I subscribe to the *start* method, and how to fix this please? Thanks.

To note: Unsure if it matters, using RX Java 1.

Doesn't work if I subscribe to following.

```
public Observable start(KafkaConsumerRecords<String, String> records) {
    return Observable.from(records.getDelegate().records().records("TOPIC_NAME"))
            .buffer(2)
            .map(this::convert)
            .map(o -> handle(o));
}
```

It works if I subscribe to the handle method directly. (By passing in a hardcoded eventObject for testing)

```
public Observable<ResultSet> handle(Object eventObject) {

    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) eventObject;
    String s1 = map.get("item1");
    String s2 = map.get("item2");

    Observable<ResultSet> rs1 = someDBInsertMethod1(s1);
    Observable<ResultSet> rs2 = someDBInsertMethod2(s2);

    return Observable.merge(rs1, rs2);
}
```

For reference, convert method takes in an Object and returns a map.

```
public Map<String, String> convert(Object records) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // add some data to map from the object records. 
    return map;
}
```

This is how I subscribe via another class in a main method.

```
// doesn't work, db insert does not happen. 
Observable result1 = myClass.start(getHardCodedRecords());
result1.subscribe(resultSet -> System.out.println("printing this thus no errors.... but no DB insert happened"));

//directly subscribing to the handle method and this time it works, able to insert into db. 
Observable result2 = myClass.handle(getHardCodedMap());
result2.subscribe(resultSet -> System.out.println("printing this thus no errors.... works"));
```